# Can a probability 0 event that is possible ever occur in a finite or infinite amount of iterations.

Tags: probability

Can an event with probability 0 that is possible occur under any circumstances? For example landing a dart at exactly 0,0 assuming a plane is drawn over the board with the origin at the bulls eye? If yes then could this happen in a countable amount of throws or only an infinite amount of throws and how would we observer the answer to this question in the real world? Sorry if I miss use any mathematical terms I do not know much about this field I just herd that possible events can have 0 probability and wanted to know what that means.

Comment: So does the probability being $0$ mean it can happen or not in the real world? How would the mathematical answer be applied in the real world? Could I ever throw a perfact dart?

Comment: Consider this. You toss a fair coin infinitely many times. The probability of getting all heads is 0. Although $(H,H,H,....)$ is a valid sequence of outcomes it's probability is 0. In fact the probability to get any fixed sequence is 0.

Comment: Chose a value $x$ uniformly in the interval $[0,1)$.  The prior probability you would have chosen precisely $x$ was $0$, but you did.

Comment: I think I am getting lost in the math words here. Simply put, would I be able to hit the bulls eye in the real world if I threw a countable number of darts or only an infinite number or darts or even at all?

Comment: If you pick a real number between $0$ and $1$ uniformly at random, the probability of getting any particular number, specified in advance, is $0$.  That doesn't mean it's impossible, since you must get *some* number.

Comment: You *can* hit the bulls-eye with one dart, whether you through one dart or a countably infinite number of darts. But in either case you almost certainly will not.

Comment: How do you throw an infinite number of darts in the real world?  Probability is a field of math, and you are asking a math question.

Comment: In the real world, darts have positive thickness, so it is is very possible to hit the point $(0,0)$ with a finite number of attempts

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when working with continuous distributions, the probability of the random variable. being a specific value is $0$. This follows directly by the properties of the real numbers. In other words think of your plane as having an infinitude amount of points and that you have to pick exactly a prescibed one. In other words, the probabilities of the whole support of your random variable must each be infinitesimal. Mathematically speaking, we say they are almost surely equal to zero. Now, going back to your example, you have to be very careful on how you define "throw a perfect dart". If you look at the dart board, the red circular target is a region and not a point. Therefore, the probability may be non-zero. If you make this region smaller and smaller, so that it converges to a point, then clearly it starts to decrease and converge to $0$.

Comment: So it true or false to say that I could hit the bulls eye in the real world assuming it is a piont on the plane?

Comment: You almost surely will not be able to hit the dart if the bulls eyes was a point on the plane, as such probability is $0$. But then again, referring to the real world application, how would you construct a dart board like that? you can make the red region as small as possible but never small enough, thus, there will always be a probability greater than zero of hitting it.

Comment: I think *"An event that has a probability zero of occurring is called an impossible event"* may be wrong.  I agree that an impossible event has probability $0$, but so too do many possible events related to continuous random variables

Comment: If we were to overlook the issues with building this board, will an event like hitting the bulls eyes while possible, ever happen?

Comment: If it is a point, then almost surely will not.

Comment: Yes or no, would it ever happen?